# PostgreSQL 9.6 wals management

Tags: postgresql, wal

I'm trying to understand my wals behavior on my PostgreSQL environment. My wal settings are :

```
wal_keep_segments = 200
max_wal_size = 3GB
min_wal_size = 80MB
archive_command = 'cp %p /PostgreSQL-wal/9.6/pg_xlog/wal_archives/%f' 
archive_timeout = 10
#checkpoint_flush_after = 256kB
#checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5
```

My wals directory is `/PostgreSQL-wal/9.6/pg_xlog/` and my archives directory is `PostgreSQL-wal/9.6/pg_xlog/wal_archives`. Last night my wals directory storage got full (archive directory also because they are on the same filing system).

I have right now 211 wals in my wals directory :

```
ls -l /PostgreSQL-wal/9.6/pg_xlog/ | wc -l
212
```

The only thing that was running during the night are only selects from our monitoring agent. I guess that wal were created because the archive_timeout was very low and they were deleted because the wal_keep_segments was high.

This morning, I set the wal_keep_segments to 100 and I set the archive_timeout to 6 minutes. Now, after setting those settings and starting the cluster wals switch is working fine and I didn't see that many wals were created. However, doesn't the old wals should be deleted automatically ? Can I delete archives safely ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max_wal_size` is not a hard limit.

When the limit is exceeded, PostgreSQL will trigger a checkpoint, at the end of which it will delete rather than recycle old WAL segments. So `pg_xlog` (`pg_wal` in new releases) can still grow until the next checkpoint.

Your setting of 3 GB corresponds to 192 WAL segments, which is lower than your `wal_keep_segments` setting (corresponds to `wal_keep_size` in new releases). So PostgreSQL won't even begin to recycle or delete WAL segments until there are 3.125 GB of them.

You should either lower `wal_keep_segments` or increase the disk space for `pg_xlog`. Once you have lowered `wal_keep_segments`, wait for a checkpoint or run `CHECKPOINT` manually. Then you will see a reduction of the number of WAL segments.

Comment: I set my wal_keep_segments to 100. Right now I have 212 wals which means 3.360G. So, shouldnt it start deleting some wals ? Regarding the archives, is it safe to delete them If i dont intent to restore the database for now ?

Comment: You should never delete files in `pg_xlog`, it can corrupt your database. I have added instructions how to reduce the size of `pg_xlog`.

Comment: You didnt understand me. I'm talking about archives - the files that are created with the archive_command.

Comment: You can always delete WAL archives, but you cannot restore the database if even a single required WAL archive is missing. I'd backup the database before removing WAL archives. Note the useful utility [`pg_archivecleanup`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgarchivecleanup.html).

Comment: A bit not clear. May you tell how `CHECKPOINT` and `pg_switch_wal()` cooperate together?

Comment: @EugenKonkov `pg_switch_wal()` has nothing to do with it. There were also some other inaccuracies in the answer. I have fixed those.